# How do I use paperclip and pdf-reader to parse PDF before uploading to S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, paperclip, pdf-reader

I'm building a feature that parses a PDF format CV. I have a method that is called on :before_save which handles parsing. I'm able to access the PDF file within this method, before it saves using...

`file = cv.queued_for_write[:original]`

But then I need to pass the file to PDF::Reader, however, it seems like pdf-reader only accepts paths or URLs to files, not the actual file itself. This approach...

`reader = PDF::Reader.new(file)`

Throws this error:

`ArgumentError (input must be an IO-like object or a filename):`

Do I need to save the file to a tmp folder or something and then pass the path to the pdf-reader to parse it? I'm hoping to parse the PDF as quickly as possible, so that doesn't seem ideal. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the "queued_for_write" object has a path attribute.

`file = cv.queued_for_write[:original]`

So I can just access it like this:

`reader = PDF::Reader.new(file.path)`